# MVVM design with subviews

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I'm very new to IOS dev and I'm designing an IOS application with swift and storyboards, trying to use the MVVM pattern.

The app has a main screen with an area that allows users to tap to add and remove "stickers" at the location of their tap. Currently I have a single view controller and one view model that has a set of Stickers and touch gestures will notify the viewModel which will in turn modify the model.

The view is bounded to the set of Stickers in the viewModel using the `Observable` pattern so whenever there are changes to that set of Stickers, the view will update. However, the way I'm doing the update is such that every `StickerView`, which is basically just an `UIImageView`, is removed and recreated whenever the set of Stickers changes. Which means when a new sticker is added or removed, a function is called to remove all existing `StickerViews`, then recreate them with the modified set of Stickers. This seems very wasteful but coming from a react background, I was trying to make the viewModel the single source of truth, to ensure a clear flow of data. My question is, is this the right way for me to do it, or is there a better, less resource intensive, yet clean way to do it?

This is the ViewModel that I have.

```swift
struct BoardViewModel {

    let stickers: Observable<Set<Sticker>>

    func getStickers() -> Set<Sticker> { ... }

    func addSticker() { ... }
  
    func removeStickers() { ... }

}
```

This is the Observable class that I got off another stack overflow post

```swift
class Observable<T> {

    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    private var listener: ((T) -> Void)?

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bind(_ closure: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        closure(value)
        listener = closure
    }
}
```

Then in my viewController, this is how I did the binding. I've excluded the gesture functions but basically, these functions will call either `addSticker` or `removeSticker` in the viewModel, causing the `Observable<Set<Sticker>>` to be modified, hence causing `renderStickers()` to be called

```swift
class viewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: BoardViewModel

    //a background image which I put the stickers on.
    @IBOutlet private var board: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        viewModel.stickers.bind { _ in
            self.renderStickers()
        }
    }
    
    private func renderStickers() {
        removeAllStickers()
        for sticker in viewModel.getStickers() {
             self.board.addSubView(StickerView(sticker))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could share some code, especially around the viewModel, that would make it much easier to discuss.

Comment: @ajmccall Yea for sure, just added some short snippets of the relevant parts

Comment: Problem I see is that you are trying to use an observer pattern in UIKit. This isn't impossible, but the tooling and architecture doesn't exist natively there. As you're new to iOS, why are you not using SwiftUI to do this? SwiftUI views support Observable view models implicitly and would be something you probably understand more intuitively.

Comment: I wanted to learn UIKit first before going into SwiftUI. In that case, how woukd you recommend I design my program if I were to continue using UIKit?